# No Continue Button is displayed even after the Dialogue is done in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't want the player to spam the continueButtonSE hence, I only want it to appear after the dialogue has finished.

It works in the first index but for the next element, the continueButton does not appear. Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class DialogueSE : MonoBehaviour
{
   public TextMeshProUGUI textDisplaySE;
   public string[] sentencesSE;
   private int index;
   public float typingSpeedSE;
   public GameObject continueButtonSE;

   void Start()
   {
     StartCoroutine(Type());
   }

   void Update()
   {
     if(textDisplaySE.text == sentencesSE[index])
     {
         continueButtonSE.SetActive(true);
     }
   }

   IEnumerator Type()
   {
     foreach (char letter in sentencesSE[index].ToCharArray())
     {
         textDisplaySE.text += letter;
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(typingSpeedSE);
     }
   }
   public void NextSentenceSE()
   {
     continueButtonSE.SetActive(false);
    
     if (index < sentencesSE.Length - 1)
     {
         index++;
         textDisplaySE.text = " ";
         StartCoroutine(Type());
     }
     else
     {
         textDisplaySE.text = " ";
         continueButtonSE.SetActive(false);
     }
   }
}
```

I've disabled the continueButtonSE from the start so that it can only appear once sentencesSE[index] is done appearing.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I've removed the `[visual-studio]` tag because this question isn't about the Visual Studio application.

Answer (score 2):

You are prepending a space when you say `textDisplaySE.text = " ";` and then you add things in the coroutine therefore `if(textDisplaySE.text == sentencesSE[index])` is never true because your in the second case textDisplaySE.text is actually `[space]test2` instead of just `test2` which is what sentencesSE[index].

On line 31 instead you can initialize to `textDisplaySE.text = string.Empty;` to not have any whitespace.

Comment: You can also use `textDisplaySE.text = "";` which might have been OP's intention. However, see also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65612205/7111561) to skip this needless string compare in `Update` entirely ;)

Comment: Got it! Thanks! <3

Answer (score 1):

*In addition to the explanation of your issue from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65607783/7111561)*

**Why do you need the check at all?**

You could simply let your Coroutine handle the end of the typing and enabling the continue button like e.g.

```
IEnumerator Type()
{
    foreach (char letter in sentencesSE[index].ToCharArray())
    {
        textDisplaySE.text += letter;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(typingSpeedSE);
    }

    if (index < sentencesSE.Length - 1)
    {
        continueButtonSE.SetActive(true);
    }
}

public void NextSentenceSE()
{
    continueButtonSE.SetActive(false);

    if (index < sentencesSE.Length - 1)
    {
        index++;
        textDisplaySE.text = "";
        StartCoroutine(Type());
    }
    else
    {
        textDisplaySE.text = "";
        Debug.Log("Reached end of dialog");
    }
}
```

This way you don't need the `Update` method and string compare at all and wouldn't even get into the issue with the prepend space character ;)